# How to show mistakes with Django Serializer Validation?

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework

I'm using Django with Django-Rest-Framework. If I run the `serializer.is_valid()` function I get a `False` result. How can I show the reason for this result?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

try it

```
is_valid(raise_exception=True)
```

Answer (score 2):

`serializer.errors` has the details of the validation errors that occured